# Rails, Backbone, Handlebars template and .erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, handlebars.js, erb

I am building a Rails app using Backbone as a front-end framework. I am using Handlebars for my templating.

On the Rails side I have a Publication model and each publication has many articles. For now I want to print my list of names of publications to the screen.

When I pass my collection of publications to the view's render function I am displaying the names just fine using this code for my handlebars template:

```
{{#each publications}}
  {{#if name}}
    <li style='color:green'>
      {{name}}
    </li>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Now what I also want is to have next to the name buttons that allow me to edit and delete just like in the views>publications>index.html.erb page that Rails originally generated. The code for that is:

```
      <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                  edit_publication_path(publication), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
      <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                  publication_path(publication),
                  :method => :delete,
                  :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                  :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
```

Since this code involved .erb tags I do not know how to integrate it into my handlebars template. Can somebody help me resolve this? Is there something fundamentally wrong with what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to rename the handlebars template file to *.hbs.erb and just use erb tags in it like normal.

Rails will compile files in the order of the file extensions from right to left.
In this case the erb content would be injected into the handlebars file, which would then be
precompiled serverside, or sent to the client and compiled at runtime (the default behavior).